# Solution of Euler equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

I have given $v$ as stationary, incompressible and irrotational flow and a constant density $\rho$.

Why $v$ is a solution of the Euler equations:

$$ \partial_t \rho + \nabla \cdot (\rho v ) = 0$$
$$ \rho \partial_t v + \rho (v \cdot \nabla ) v = - \nabla p $$

where $ p = - \frac{\rho}{2} |v|^2$ ?

How can I show this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\nu$ is stationary and incompressible, then that means $\partial_t \nu=0$ and $\nabla \cdot \nu=0$.

Since $\rho$ is constant, then it follows
\begin{align}
\partial_t \rho +\nabla\cdot(\rho \nu)=0+\rho\nabla\cdot\nu = 0.
\end{align}

Next, we have
\begin{align}
\rho\partial_t\nu +\rho(\nu\cdot \nabla)\nu= \rho\cdot 0+\rho \nu\cdot \nabla\nu =\frac{1}{2}\rho\nabla|\nu|^2 =-\nabla\left(-\frac{1}{2}\rho |\nu|^2\right)=-\nabla p.
\end{align}